# Can you remove a style sheet for a certain device?

Tags: jquery, iphone, mobile, stylesheet, media-queries

I'm building a mobile version of a site (not a mobile.domain.com) but just serving up a different style sheet based upon the device.

So I have something like this:

```
<link href="css/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/mobile1.css" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width = 320px, initial-scale=1" />
```

My mobile style sheet is obviously hiding/showing only what I want on the mobile site, and then overriding classes/styles in the `style.css`.

The problem I'm having is I can't seem to find what style I'm not overriding.  Meaning, if I completely **remove** `style.css` - the site looks perfect.  If I **keep** `style.css` in there, it looks not so perfect.

Is there a way for me to dynamically remove the style.css when the page loads?

Or am I going about this the complete wrong way.

Comment: Does `media="handheld"` not work for you?

Comment: media="handheld" doesnt work on iPhones

Comment: Might want to tag this iphone then too might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up just giving my stylesheet an ID and did this:

```
jQuery('#mainStyleSheet').remove();
```

I did this after checking what the screen size was.  if less than 480, then I remove my old style sheet.  Seems to work quite well - not sure it's an ideal solution though.

Comment: Well, what does iPhone report itself as, if not handheld? (I don't know, since I'm not a mobile developer, but if it reports itself as something distinct, you could use that.)

Comment: reports itself as Screen.  YOu end up having to use media queries

Comment: Oh.
Well, I gave it a shot, not being a mobile developer, I didn't know any better. I wish you luck!

Answer (score 0):

This example works for Internet Explorer, but you'll have to find out the proper calling name for iPhone:

```
<!--[if !IE]> //This will target everything except Internet Explorer browsers.
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> //Add appropriate stylesheet.
<![endif]-->
```

---

```
<!--[if !iPhone]>
    ...
<![endif]-->
```

Could work. I'm not sure and don't have an iPhone to check against this.